# Calculating change in score and adding to a new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to calculate the changed in mental health scores of each individual between two timepoints.

Each user has a name, and a mental health score from 3 different timepoints. I would like to calculate the change in mental health score between timepoint 3 and 1

Below is example of df I'm starting with:

```
User   Timepoint   Mental Health Score
Bill       1               5
Bill       2               10
Bill       3               15
Wiz        1               10
Wiz        2               10
Wiz        3               15
Sam        1               5
Sam        2               5
Sam        3               5
```

This is desired output:

```
User   Timepoint   Mental Health Score      Change in Mental Health (TP1 and 3) 
Bill       1               5                               
Bill       2               10
Bill       3               15                              10
Wiz        1               10
Wiz        2               10
Wiz        3               15                              5
Sam        1               5
Sam        2               5
Sam        3               5                               0
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? You should add your current attempt to your question and explain how it is deficient. Pandas has excellant documentation, it would be worthwhile spending some time working your way through its [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html).

Comment: One way - In short: groupby `'User'`; sort each group on `'Timepoint'`; get the difference between the last and first items in the group.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using `shift()` and `np.where()`

```
df['Change in Mental Health (TP1 and 3)'] = df['Mental Health Score'] - df['Mental Health Score'].shift(2)
df['Change in Mental Health (TP1 and 3)'] = np.where(df['Timepoint'] != 3, 0, df['Change in Mental Health (TP1 and 3)']).astype(int)
df
```

Comment: perhaps need to do `df.sort_values(['User', 'Timepoint'])` before `.shift(2)` can be effective?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `groupby` and `where`:

```
#sort by Timepoint if needed
#df = df.sort_values("Timepoint")

changes = df.groupby("User")["Mental Health Score"].transform('last')-df.groupby("User")["Mental Health Score"].transform('first')
df["Change"] = changes.where(df["Timepoint"].eq(3))

>>> df
   User  Timepoint  Mental Health Score  Change
0  Bill          1                    5     NaN
1  Bill          2                   10     NaN
2  Bill          3                   15    10.0
3   Wiz          1                   10     NaN
4   Wiz          2                   10     NaN
5   Wiz          3                   15     5.0
6   Sam          1                    5     NaN
7   Sam          2                    5     NaN
8   Sam          3                    5     0.0
```

Comment: need to `df.groupby(["User", "Timepoint"])` just in case the `Timepoint` column is not sorted

Comment: No, that shouldn't be grouped. It should be sorted. If it isn't, OP can simply do `df = df.sort_values("Timepoint")` before running the above.

Comment: oh sorry i mean `df.sort_values(['User', 'Timepoint'])`

Comment: Only sorting by "Timepoint" is enough. I didn't add this because OP's dataframe was already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated already in the comments you can `groupby` your dataframe on `User` and calculate difference on `Mental Health Score`

I put a snippet code here to demonstrate

```
def _overall_change(scores):
  return scores.iloc[-1] - scores.iloc[0]

person = df.groupby('User')['Score'].agg(_overall_change)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` and a `merge`:

```
g = df.sort_values(by='Timepoint').groupby('User')['Mental Health Score']

s = pd.concat({3: g.last()-g.first()})
#    User
# 3  Bill    10
#    Sam      0
#    Wiz      5
# Name: Mental Health Score, dtype: int64

df.merge(s, left_on=['Timepoint', 'User'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

output:

```
   User  Timepoint  Mental Health Score_x  Mental Health Score_y
0  Bill          1                      5                    NaN
1  Bill          2                     10                    NaN
2  Bill          3                     15                   10.0
3   Wiz          1                     10                    NaN
4   Wiz          2                     10                    NaN
5   Wiz          3                     15                    5.0
6   Sam          1                      5                    NaN
7   Sam          2                      5                    NaN
8   Sam          3                      5                    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd

def calculate_change(mhs):
    mhs = list(mhs)
    return mhs[-1] - mhs[0]

df = df.sort_values(["User", "Timepoint"])
diff = df.groupby('User')['Mental Health Score'].agg(calculate_change)

df = pd.merge(df, diff, how='left', left_on='User', right_index=True)
df.columns = ['User', 'Timepoint', 'Mental Health Score', 'Change']
df['Change'] = df['Change'].loc[df['Timepoint']==3]
print(df)
```

Output

```
   User  Timepoint  Mental Health Score  Change
0  Bill          1                    5     NaN
1  Bill          2                   10     NaN
2  Bill          3                   15    10.0
3   Wiz          1                   10     NaN
4   Wiz          2                   10     NaN
5   Wiz          3                   15     5.0
6   Sam          1                    5     NaN
7   Sam          2                    5     NaN
8   Sam          3                    5     0.0
```